# How can I replace this for loop with an STL implementation?

Tags: c++, functional-programming, stl, iterator, c++17

I have this little for-loop here (variables and types renamed):

```cpp
vector<Iterator> validIterators;

for (auto itr = someStartIterator; itr != someVector.end(); itr++)
{
  if (itr->foo() && itr->bar())
    validIterators.push_back(itr); // Notice that I'm not deferencing the iterator when adding it to the vector
}

...

for (const auto& itr : validIterators)
{
  // Do stuff with the iterator explicitly (e.g. std::distance),
  // and not the object that it points (at least not at first).
}
```

Is there any way to use the STL `<algorithm>` functions to make something "cleaner"? I can't use Boost in that context, nor C++20 ranges or range-v3.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If I have understood correctly you can use the standard algorithm std::copy_if

Comment: ...into a `back_inserter`.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow that was my intuition at first, but I do need the actual iterator, not a copy of the object that it points to.

Comment: @FireYoshi -- ?? You *are* getting the iterator when you use `copy_if`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie the only iterator that `copy_if` provides is the "iterator to the element in the destination range, one past the last element copied" as its return value. The elements are otherwise copied by value : https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy

Comment: @FireYoshi: "*Notice that I'm not deferencing the iterator*" But you are derefencing the iterator. That's what `itr->foo()` is doing.

Comment: @NicolBolas I meant when adding it to the vector, but that is correct.

Comment: I am confused why people are so enthusiastic about using complicated code with standard algorithms instead of nice plain loops. Does this come from languages like python or matlab where you have to express everything in terms of standard numpy/matrix operations or pay a large penalty?

Comment: @MarcGlisse The only reason this is complicated is because it steps _outside_  the standard algorithms

Answer (score 1):

Algorithms, by their nature, operate on sequences of values. They interface with these sequence of values through an intermediary object called an "iterator". But this is, from the implementation's perspective, an implementation detail. A necessary one, to be sure, but it is still not really part of the algorithm.

As such, algorithms do not typically expose the iterators to user-provided functors. `std::for_each` passes the functor a value extracted from the iterator, not the iterator itself. `std::sort`'s predicate compares pairs of values, not pairs of iterators. `std::copy_if` copies values based on a predicate which is provided a value. And so forth. Even the range-based `for` loop itself doesn't expose the iterators.

Algorithms manipulate values *through* their iterators, not the iterators themselves.

Your best bet is to do the loop manually and fold the "act on the iterator" part into the conditional testing part.

```
for (auto itr = someStartIterator; itr != someVector.end(); itr++)
{
  if (itr->foo() && itr->bar())
  {
    // Do stuff with the `itr` explicitly (e.g. std::distance).
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, after reading your answer I realized I didn't have any use for `validIterators`; folding it in the conditional makes more sense.

Answer (score 1):

The standard library algorithms uses iterators to work on some underlying data and the iterators themselves are not available through the standard library algorithms. You'll have to write your own algorithm for that.

Example:

```
template<class Iterator, class Func>
std::vector<Iterator> get_valid_iterators(Iterator Begin, Iterator End, Func f) {
    std::vector<Iterator> rv;

    for(; Begin != End; ++Begin)
        if(f(Begin)) rv.push_back(Begin); // f is functor that can validate the iterator

    return rv;
}
```

Usage:

```
auto vi = get_valid_iterators(container.begin(), container.end(),
                              [](auto& it) { return it->foo() && it->bar(); });
```